# Printing list with polish letters

Tags: windows, python-2.7, list, character-encoding

I am writing a simple program for windows using Python 2.7. It opens an email, take some words from it and puts them in a form on web. Problem starts when the email contains polish letters like Ó, Ź, Ł etc. Whenever I try to print it I get something like: ['\xc4\x84', '\xc5\xbb', '\xc3\x93', '\xc4\x86', '\xc5\xb9'].
I already know it is because of encoding and that Python 3 has no such problem. Here is what I tried already:

```
mail = " Ą Ż Ó Ć Ź"
mail = mail.split()
mail = mail.decode("UTF-8")
print mail
```

or

```
mail = " Ą Ż Ó Ć Ź"
mail = mail.split()
[x.encode('UTF8') for x in mail]
print mail
```

Can anyone please show me how to make the list print properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x uses ASCII as a default encoding. To force it to use Unicode, add this line to the top of your program.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also you should prefix any string literals with 'u'. e.g.

```
polishLetters = u'Ą Ż Ó Ć Ź'
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I have tried to add the line from above before, but only got: "SyntaxError: encoding declaration in Unicode string (<string>, line 0)" for my trouble. For some reason I forgot to mention it in the descritpion of the problem.